# Confused about final answer for vector space of polynomials.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

a friend and I are working on some problems in linear algebra, and we have come to a bit of stump unto the correct way to look at this. The questions asks " Let T be a subspace of polynomials P2(t) spanned by, $$ p_1= 1+t+t^2 $$ 
 $$ 
p_2= 2 + 2t + 2t^2 $$

$$ p_3=-t $$

$$ p_4=1+t^2 $$(given in the question). Find a subset of the polynomials that form a basis for T.

Here is where the confusion is. I wrote the vectors as columns and row reduced, then chose the columns that had leading entries ( p1 and p3 ) ie in the form $$  \begin{matrix} 1 & 2 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \end{matrix}$$

and said that these polynomials form a basis. However my friend says that in fact there are five answers, because any of the other polynomials other then {p1,p2} are linear combinations?

Is that true? To me it seems as if the only correct answer is the one with the leading entries?

Thanks all

Comment: Correct your $\;p_4\;$

Comment: okay I fixed it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your friend is correct.  In fact there is only one set of two vectors that you *can't* choose: $\{p_1, p_2\}$.

To see why multiple answers are possible try this: Write the vectors in a different order.  Specifically try switching $p_1$ and $p_4$ and then do exactly what you did before (write down a matrix, row reduce it, choose vectors corresponding to leading $1$'s).

Notice that when you write down the polynomials in the order $p_4, p_2, p_3, p_1$ your algorithm tells you to pick $\{p_4, p_2\}$.

Basically the algorithm you're using is just one way to choose vectors.  Specifically it's always going to give you the *first* vectors in the list that work.  When you listed them in order $p_1, p_2, p_3, p_4$ it picked $p_1$ first (it will always pick the first vector no matter what order you put these $4$ vectors in).  Then it saw it couldn't pick $p_2$ so it picked $p_3$ which was next.  When you listed them in order $p_4, p_2, p_3, p_1$ it picked $p_4$ first and picked $p_2$ second, so it chooses the first two vectors that it's allowed to choose.